# Simulate Memory Warning While Running Instruments?

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, instruments

Is there a way to do this? If so, how, and can it be done while running an app in the simulator and/or the real device?

Is there an alternative way to test response to memory warnings in Instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the device, as far as I know, the only way to have a memory warning is actually creating a low memory condition. You can do that by allocating a big chunk of memory and freeing it after a few seconds (don't forget to release it, anyway).
This may appear like a hack, but is the most reliable way of producing a low memory condition.

About the simulator, as you possibly know, using Instruments to check for memory/performance issues while running your app within the simulator is not entirely reliable. Anyway, if you would like to do that, you can try sending this notification:

```
- (void)simulateMemoryWarning
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  #ifdef DEBUG
    CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),   (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
  #endif
 #endif
}
```

([Source](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/05/04/debugging-magic-auto-simulate-memory-warnings/))

Remember also that the simulator has got the "Hardware/Simulate Memory Warning" command.

Comment: I find it works best to call this from a timer, so I can set up the desired application state manually, then have the memory warning sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a memory warning while running the iPhone Simulator by going to the menu and selecting : Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning, which can be done at anytime even during running Instruments .